# How to wait for data in subscribe

Tags: angular

I have a problem with this service in angular. When I want to get users' roles by token from backend and in method hasrole() check this role - I get undefined data. Because data roles don't exist yet. When I run this service a second time it works great. How to get data and tell service to wait for them.

```
export class JwtService {

  roles: string[] = [];
  
  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient,
    private loginService: LoginService
  ) { }

  hasRole(rolea: string): boolean {
    if (this.roles.length  === 0) {
      this.saveRole();
    }
    return this.roles.includes(rolea);
  }

  saveRole() {
    this.http.get<string[]>(`/api/getRole/${this.getToken()}`).subscribe(role => this.roles = role);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Update** replace the "switchMap" by "map"
Remember: "Your services return Observables, you subscribe in components."

You can re-structure your service in the way

```
//see that return an observable
//You use rxjs operator "of"
hasRole(rolea: string): Observable<boolean> {
    if (this.roles.length  === 0) {
      return this.saveRole().pipe(
        //use switchMap, to return not the observable that return the roles
        //else an observable "true|false"
        switchMap((roles:string[])=>{
           this.roles=roles; //<--store the roles
           return of(this.roles.includes(roles))
        })
      )
    }
    else
      return of(this.roles.includes(roles))
  }
```

```
//see that return an observable
//You use rxjs operator "of"
hasRole(rolea: string): Observable<boolean> {
    if (this.roles.length  === 0) {
      return this.saveRole().pipe(
        map((roles:string[])=>{
           this.roles=roles; //<--store the roles
           return this.roles.includes(roles)
        })
      )
    }
    else
      return of(this.roles.includes(roles))
  }


  //I imagine that your function getToken() also return an Observable
  saveRole():Observable<string[]> {
    return this.getToken().pipe(
        switchMap((token:string)=>
                    this.http.get<string[]>(`/api/getRole/${this.getToken()}`));
  }
```

So you can use some like

```
  <div *ngIf="myService.hasRole('admin')|async">
      I am admin
  </div>
```

Comment: yes, and use swithMap when the correct is use "map", as @Avraham has response  correctly

Answer (score 1):

The `hasRole` should return an `Observable` like this:

```
hasRole(role: string): Observable<boolean>{
    if (this.roles.length  === 0) {
      return this.saveRole().pipe(
                 map(roles => roles.includes(rolea))
             );
    }else{
      return of(this.roles.includes(rolea));
    }
    

saveRole(): Observable<string[]> {
    return this.http.get<string[]> 
           (`/api/getRole/${this.getToken()}`).pipe(
             tap(roles => this.roles = roles)
          );
  }
```

And then subscribe to it in your component:

```
JwtService.hasRole('someRole').subscribe(hasRole => this.hsRole = hasRole)
```

`tap` & `map` are both rxjs operators, `tap` is for side effects and `map` just maps the value into something else - in your case into a boolean.

`of` is a rxjs function that instantiate an `Observable` on go with the value you supply. In this case, we used it to return an `Observable` when no `http` request is needded since the data is already fetched.